# Specific BCNF decomposition

Tags: database-design, bcnf

I'm trying  to do a BCNF decomposition of the following relation:

```
R(A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

with functional dependencies:

```
A -> DF
B -> AC
F -> E
```

I get the superkey to B, and by following the decomposition algorithm for BCNF I get
the following decomposition:

```
R1{ADF}, R2{ABC} R3{FE}
```

However, I suspect that R3 is not correct. Can anyone explain why, and where my error is?

Comment: B is the only candidate key. Your decomposition is correct.

Comment: Thank you Mike! I read some more about BCNF and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: I guess I should have put that as an answer.

Comment: Yes.  Upvotes on comments don't help you in the REP department.  If you care about that.