# Database Normalization BCNF decomposition

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have a relation schema M with the attributes {B, C, D, E, R} and the following set of functional dependencies:

1. B, D, E -> R
2. B, D, R -> E
3. B, C, D -> R
4. C, D -> E

I want to perform a BCNF decomposition for this schema. The key of this relation schema is {B, C, D}.

I followed the BCNF decomposition algorithm, and in the first step, I identified the functional dependency B, D, E -> R. According to the algorithm, I should create two components: R1 {B, D, E, R} and R2 {B, C, D, E}.

Now, my question is about removing the attribute R from the original relation schema. R appears on both the left and right sides of functional dependencies B, D, R -> E and B, C, D -> R. However, B, C, D -> R is already in BCNF, and if I remove both of these dependencies, I'm left with only C, D -> E.

I haven't come across examples that cover this specific scenario. What could I have done wrong in this situation?

Comment: PKs are not relevant to DB normalization except that they are CKs. There are many algorithms, which are you using &  from where? Why/how are you 1st stuck/unsure? What do you mean, "only"? Why does that matter? What is your reasoning showing that what you noticed can't arise according to a BCNF definition or algorithm? How is noticing it stopping you from following your algorithm?

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: [Functional dependencies after normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374962/3404097) [Getting the same FDs you start with after BCNF decomposition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226057/3404097)

Comment: And these are all the FDs that hold. The algorithm is below:

Algorithm for a BCNF-decomposition
Input: a relation schema R0 and a set Σ of FDs on R0.
Output: a set S of relation schemas in BCNF, each having a set of FDs
Start with S = {R0};
Do the following for each R ∈ S iteratively until no changes on S:
Find a (non-trivial) FD X → Y on R that violates BCNF, if any;
Replace R in S by two relation schemas XY and (R − Y) and
project the FDs to these two relation schemas.

Comment: And I just don't know how will this R-Y work for my problem? If I remove all RDs contains R, what I left will only C, D -> E. But according to this algorithm, I should have two new relation schemas XY and (R-Y）, and only one contains Y, i.e. R in my problem.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please act on everything my earlier comments. PS Including: What does the source of the algorithm say "relation schema" & "a set of FDs on a schema" & "project a FD onto a schema" mean? What is your justification that you correctly followed the directions expressed via those phrases? PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please don't say that your question is such & such or that it is about such & such, just give the necessary background & ask the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's follow the algorithm that you have shown in a comment.

The FD `B,D,E -> R` violates the BCNF, since the only candidate key of the schema is `B,D,C`, so we split the schema in two subschemas:

```
R1(B,D,E,R)  (all the attributes of the FD)
R2(B,D,C,E)  (the attributes of the relation without the determinate, R)
```

The closure of the projection of the FDs on R1 is:

```
B,D,E -> R
B,D,R -> E
```

so the schema is in BCNF, since the only two candidate keys are `(B,D,E)` and `(B,D,R)` and in both FD the determinant is a candidate key.

The closure of the projection of the FDs on R2 is:

```
C,D -> E
```

but, since `(C,D)` is not a candidate key for R2 (the candidate key is `(B,C,D)`), we have to split this schema in two schemas:

```
R3(C,D,E), with closure of the projected FDs C,D -> E
R4(B,C,D), with no non-trivial dependencies
```

so both are in BCNF.

So the final, correct, decomposition is R1, R3, R4, and such decomposition preserves both data and dependencies.

Comment: I have another question. There is a saying that 'a BCNF-decomposition that is both lossless and dependency-preserving does not always exist.' So, I used to think that R1 would contain only one FD, i.e., B, D, E -> R. Therefore, B, D, R -> E is lost, and the decomposition is not dependency-preserving. Does this make sense?

Comment: One thing are the FDs given in a certain case, let's call them a set F, and another one is the *closure* of a set of FDs, usually called F+, obtained by applying in all possible ways the so-called Armstrong’s axioms. For this reason one should give the *minimal cover* of a set of dependencies, that is the minimal set of dependencies equivalent to anothe set. For instance, in your example, a possible cover of the dependency is {B, D, E -> R; B, D, R -> E; C, D -> E}. From these all the other dependencies can be derived. So certain dependencies that seems lost are no lost at all...

Comment: And the normalization algorithms are more simple if they are applied to a relation schema with a minimal cover. Moreover, there exists equivalent definition of normal forms with a minimal cover for the dependencies.

Comment: Got it, thanks!